# Different Window Form

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I have been using directx for a while now and one thing that has always bothered me is that windows are squares (I guess this applies to most programs). Now as creation often happens by defining a rectangle shape and drawing that, black for example. I have been thinking of 2 approaches to this:

- Define a bigger rectangle and draw parts of the background transparent.

I decided not to go for this one as I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

- See what microsoft offers when it comes to window shapes.

And while they did have a lot of win32 configuration settings (no border etc) I couldn't find anything about drawing in a particular shape (like using a triangle for example).

Does anyone have experience with window shapes or drawing a background transparent? Maybe even a better option that I missed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure how it would work with DirectX, but you could look online for `SetWindowRgn`, a WinAPI to... set the window region.

Comment: That looks really cool, could you perhaps give a mini example? (like taking out a pixel or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite simply using the `SetWindowRgn` API call.  What this does is define the area within which the system will allow drawing to appear.

As a simple example, lets punch a hole in one of our windows.  The following can be done in the WM_CREATE handler of the window:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // Get the window rect
        RECT r;
        GetWindowRect(m_hwnd, &r);
        MapWindowPoints(NULL, m_hwnd, reinterpret_cast<LPPOINT>(&r), 2);
        // Work out the size of the window
        LONG w = r.right - r.left;
        LONG h = r.bottom - r.top;
        // Create a rectangular region to cover the window (almost)
        HRGN hRgn = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&r);
        // and a smaller elliptical window
        r.left += w/4;
        r.right -= w/4;
        r.top += h/4;
        r.bottom -= h/4;
        HRGN rgnCirc = CreateEllipticRgnIndirect(&r);

        // Now we combine the two regions, using XOR to create a hole
        int cres = CombineRgn(hRgn, rgnCirc, hRgn, RGN_XOR);

        // And set the region.
        SetWindowRgn(m_hwnd, hRgn, TRUE);
    }
    break;
```

Some important notes.  The region that is passed to `SetWindowRgn` is from that point on owned by the system, so do not perform any more operations on it.  Also, you would need to modify the region if the window is resized - I only put the example in `WM_CREATE` as... an example.

Another little caveat about the above, it doesn't perform the calculation of window size correctly... as I said, this is just an example that punches a hole in a window.

Finally, I tried it with a simple Direct-X program, and it works with that too. Hoorah!